# @org.gradle.api.tasks.Optional doesn't work

Tags: java, gradle

I have `gradle` plugin, and I need one of the options to be optional. According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Optional.html) I need use `@Optional` attribute in getter for the option to be optional.

This is the extention:

```java
public interface BCBPluginExtension
{
    Property<String> getOutputPath();
}
```

The task:

```java
public class Compile extends DefaultTask
{
    private final Property<String> outputPath = getProject().getObjects().property(String.class);

    @Optional
    @Input
    public Property<String> getOutputPath() {
        return outputPath;
    }

    @TaskAction
    public void compile() {...}
}
```

Main class:

```java
public class BCBPlugin implements Plugin<Project>
{
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project)
    {
        BCBPluginExtension extension = project.getExtensions().create("project", BCBPluginExtension.class);
        TaskParams params = TaskParams.of(project, extension, new BCBConfiguration());

        project.getTasks().create("build", Compile.class, task -> configureBuildTask(params, task));
    }

    private void prepareBuildTask(TaskParams params, Compile task)
    {
        task.getProjectDirectory().set(params.getProject().getRootDir().toString());
        task.getBorlandDir().set(params.getExtension().getBorlandDir());
        task.getOutputPath().set(params.getExtension().getOutputPath());
        task.getRebuild().set(params.getExtension().getRebuild());
        task.getLeaveTemporary().set(params.getExtension().getLeaveTemporary());
        task.getSilent().set(params.getExtension().getSilent());
        task.getStopOnFailure().set(params.getExtension().getStopOnFailure());
        task.getExecTimeout().set(params.getExtension().getTimeout());
        task.setBCBConfiguration(params.getCompiler());
    }

    private void configureBuildTask(TaskParams params, Compile task) {
        setGroup(task);
        task.setDescription("Сборка");
        task.dependsOn("prepare");

        prepareBuildTask(params, task);
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.helga.gradlebcb' version '0.7'
}

project {
    borlandDir = 'T:\\'
}
```

One another question: is there some more manuals about custom `gradle` plugins except [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-create-plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so all we need, is declare the class as abstract, as well to declare the getters as abstract:

```
public abstract class Compile extends DefaultTask
{
    // remove private final Property<String> outputPath from here

    @Optional
    @Input
    public abstract Property<String> getOutputPath();

    @TaskAction
    public void compile() {...}
}
```